# An API to get wallet balance for all networks

Tags: web3j, java

I'm trying to develop a centralizated way to take a wallet addres balance but I need to know if that address have any money in every chain network ( or most of them ).

For now I have to create a WEB3 object for every network I want to check, but I think this is not the best way to do it.

```
    this.networks.put("Binance BSC", Web3j.build(new HttpService( "https://bsc-dataseed.binance.org" ) ) );
    this.networks.put("MATIC Polygon", Web3j.build(new HttpService( "https://polygon-rpc.com" ) ) );
    this.networks.put("MATIC Polygon Llama", Web3j.build(new HttpService( "https://polygon.llamarpc.com" ) ) );
    this.networks.put("Ethereum", Web3j.build(new HttpService( "https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/<API_KEY>" ) ) );
    this.networks.put("AVAX Avalanche", Web3j.build(new HttpService( "https://api.avax.network/ext/bc/C/rpc" ) ) );
```

and then:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Web3j> entry : this.networks.entrySet()) {
    
    EthGetBalance ethGetBalance = entry.getValue().ethGetBalance(address, DefaultBlockParameterName.LATEST).send();
    BigDecimal res = Convert.fromWei( ethGetBalance.getBalance().toString() , Unit.ETHER );

}
```

Is there any way to check it in just one hit?